# Is there a generic software for LED banners?

Tags: led, software

I have a scrolling LED banner (16 LED's tall, like those stock tickers), and the software that it comes with is lacking the functions that I need. Is there a more advanced generic software that can send messages to an LED banner?

I would like the software to automatically read an RSS feed and upload messages to the screen.

Comment: probably a link to the banner or a schematic is required.

Comment: Here is a link to the banner (original website in Spanish): http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lumtecdisplays.com%2Fhtml%2Fpantallas_led_unilineas_2.html&act=url

Comment: And here is the communication protocol: http://www.mediafire.com/?fn1zz4wah2o9imc

Answer (score 2):

This sign is driven by a serial protocol defined in the PDF you linked. The various hexadecimal codes instruct the sign what characters to display, colors to use, etc. From this, I deduce that the sign contains hardware that is responsible for rendering characters, scrolling them, and the various functions outlined in the protocol specification.

Simply put, if the documentation does not contain the function you need, there is no way to produce such output without bypassing some hardware.

The answer to your question "Is there a generic software for LED banners?" is: ***no; it varies from manufacturer to manufacturer***. Some LED sign companies produce signs that are compatible with standard video signals (DVI for example) and these allow you to use whatever content-creation software you like; the sign simply renders a portion of the signal.

In order to modify the sign you linked, you would need a schematic showing how the LED's are wired. At that point, you may be able to create your own driver hardware to achieve the desired effect. An Arduino may be capable of driving such a banner, depending on how the LED circuit is designed.